# Show values and sample size in balloon plot in R - ggballoonplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

given the data

```r
mockdata <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,0.5,6,1,0.8,7,0.8,1,6,1,1,8),
                              ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))

colnames(mockdata) <- c("percentage_a","percentage_b", "sample_size")

rownames(mockdata) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

I wanted to have each balloon coloured by the value and sized by the column sample_size.

with the following code

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggballoonplot(mockdata,  fill = "value")+
  geom_text(aes(label=value), alpha=1.0, size=3, nudge_x = 0.15)*
```

I get the following graph:

[image: graph]

I can't seem to manage to use the *sample_size* as size of the respective column.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `ggballoonplot` is the right tool for data in this format. In any case, this function is just a thin wrapper around some fairly basic ggplot code, and it is straightforward to make the plot you want directly. This gives you full control over all the plot elements.

The key is to convert your row names to a column, then pivot the two percentage columns into long format to get the data in the right format for plotting.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mockdata %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("percentage")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, rowname, fill = value, size = sample_size)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(4, 8), range = c(2, 8)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>